# PHP: Get content from HTTPS website

Tags: php, ssl, https, file-get-contents

What I'm trying to do is creating a page to show my accounts balance. I got a bit sick of logging into my bank accounts using username and password since I've got two different with (luckily) very long/twisted password. So I want to code this self-login and then show the balance. That's it. No money transfer, nor payments.. Just the balance! But I thought it was a bit easier.. I mean, I know it's a bank website so it must be secure, but if I login remotely (let's say I'm able to make it) giving you my credentials, why don't you work? Why you just work on your own server? I know ssl, https, verisign, etc. But do you think there's any way I can do this? Of course there are no API's for third party developers, I have to find a way myself.

So this is what I did: I tried to log into the first bank account "remotely" (let's call bank.com the bank website). So if the page bank.com/login has a form with username and password, I made a localhost/login page that looks exactly the same. In fact, the action is the same as well, so after logging in I will be redirected anyway to my bank account (i.e. bank.com/dashboard). Simple? Not really.. There's a hidden field, a token, which changes every x time. So apart from what I did already, I should be able to add to my form this field as well. I should simulate this process from localhost: go to the bank website, enter the login area, browse the form, find the hidden field (token) and take note of it. Then add it to my localhost form and, eventually, log in from there. Well, the login area on bank.com is under https protocol so I can't access its content. My plan epically failed. Or not? I tried using **file_get_contents** to flush the bank.com/login content into localhost/login page, but it doesn't work. It looks like it's protected (verisign) cause the page is loaded completely, but part of its content is not available as it shows **Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException**. I guess it's part of the verisign handshake, so the content is available just after this process. Do you have any idea? Should I give up instead? :)

Comment: You're basically simulating a XSRF attack. If a bank allowed that I'd be extremely surprised.

Comment: Being that even though you don't **want** to transfer funds etc, it uses the same platform for everthing which is web based.  THis is why there are strict compliance issues for browsers and JavaScript with the transferring of information to and from your bank (including passwords).  I would hope for internet security, that this is impossible.  If you DO figure it out, let me know what bank you have so that I may change banks if I happen to have my $$ stored there.

Comment: Instead of initiating the login process from an HTML page on another domain, why not write a script (in PHP, Python, Ruby, etc.) using a high level HTTP API (such as Requests or Mechanize) that runs on your desktop computer? You can then programmatically "click" all the links and buttons on the bank's website to grab the balance once a certain page is reached. From the bank server's perspective, the request would appear to be originating from a browser, so you shouldn't run into any cross-domain or authentication trouble.

Comment: Thanks guys! This was an attempt, the basic idea was to try to code a webapp and, if it worked, to develop an iOS app as well. How do mobile apps work if there's no way for logging in? Anyway.. I might go for @Vortico solution, but I don't know anything about Requests nor Mechanize.. Do you know some good reference website? Thank you!

Comment: Here are the project sites for [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) and [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). I'm not a PHP developer, but after Googling, I found [Httpful](http://phphttpclient.com/) and [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) which may be more familiar if you are monolingual.